# Image Compressor

Tags: java, image-compression

So I've been trying to make a compressor app using an online video, but something's just not right. I've been getting errors with the compress button, and the size isn't showing, either.

I just don't know what the problem seems to be. It's my first time asking here. So I'll post the full code, just in case.

Help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int RESULT_IMAGE=1;
    ImageView imgOriginal, imgCompressed;
    TextView txtOriginal, txtCompressed, txtQuality;
    EditText txtHeight, txtWidth;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    Button btnPick, btnCompress;
    File originalImage, compressedImage;
    private static String filepath;
    File path=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myCompressor");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        askPermission();

        imgOriginal=findViewById(R.id.imgOriginal);
        imgCompressed=findViewById(R.id.imgCompressed);
        txtOriginal=findViewById(R.id.txtOriginal);
        txtCompressed=findViewById(R.id.txtCompressed);
        txtQuality=findViewById(R.id.txtQuality);
        txtHeight=findViewById(R.id.txtHeight);
        txtWidth=findViewById(R.id.txtWidth);
        seekBar=findViewById(R.id.seekQuality);
        btnPick=findViewById(R.id.btnPick);
        btnCompress=findViewById(R.id.btnCompress);

        filepath=path.getAbsolutePath();
        if (!path.exists()){
            path.mkdirs();
        }
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            txtQuality.setText("Quality: "+ i);
            seekBar.setMax(100);
        }
        @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
            });
        btnPick.setOnClickListener(view -> openGallery());
        btnCompress.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            int quality=seekBar.getProgress();
            int width=Integer.parseInt(txtWidth.getText().toString());
            int height=Integer.parseInt(txtHeight.getText().toString());
        
            try {
                compressedImage=new Compressor(MainActivity.this)
                        .setMaxWidth(width)
                        .setMaxHeight(height)
                        .setQuality(quality)
                        .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
                        .setDestinationDirectoryPath(filepath)
                        .compressToFile(originalImage);
                File finalFile=new File(filepath,originalImage.getName());
                Bitmap finalBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(finalFile.getAbsolutePath());
                imgCompressed.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap);
                txtCompressed.setText("Size: "+Formatter.formatShortFileSize(MainActivity.this, finalFile.length()));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Compressed and Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}

private void openGallery() {
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, RESULT_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        btnCompress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        assert data != null;
        final Uri imageUri=data.getData();
        try{
            final InputStream imageStream=getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            imgOriginal.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            originalImage=new File(imageUri.getPath().replace("raw/",""));
            txtOriginal.setText("Size: " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(MainActivity.this, originalImage.length()));

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something Went Wrong!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void askPermission() {
    Dexter.withContext(this)
            .withPermissions(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport multiplePermissionsReport) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> list, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                    permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();

                }
            }).check();
}
```

}